# Java text component calculate its own preferred size

Tags: java, swing, text

I am making a customised swing component and I have hit a problem. I want a simple text display (like a jlabel) that changes colour over time. Currently I have extended JPanel and overridden paintComponent(Graphics) to create a component that can draw the text it's given and cycle the colours as required. However, I do not know how to make it always draw the text in the centre of the component, nor how to make it calculate its own default preferred size (as I do not know the exact dimensions of the text) e.g. a JLabel with text set automatically returns the right value for getPreferredSize and the text always fits neatly into the label, this is the functionality I am looking to emulate. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not simply use JLabel then? And in fact if you do this, there might be no reason to override paintComponent (or even to extend JLabel), since you could simply change its foreground color in a Swing Timer.

Comment: This is a learning exercise, I'm more interested in the concept than the result. Otherwise that's pretty much how I'd have done it ;)

Comment: Then this should have been stated in the original question and we wouldn't have to waste our time answering an incomplete question.  The correct answer to the question as stated is to simply use a JLabel.  Otherwise you will need to use FontMetrics as noted in z5h's post (1+ to him).

Comment: My apologies. I didn't notice when typing the question that that was the obvious answer. However, there is no need to be rude about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FontMetrics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) class is used to determine the geometry of rendered text with a specific font. This will tell you how much space you need to render your text.
Take a look at the `getLineMetrics` methods.